# Search results disappear when looking at last page

Tags: bug, search

If I search `""`, then there are millons of results, but if I click the button to go to the last page, the results change to 0 and errors "We couldn't find anything for your search". If we go to page 1 it goes back to normal, the search is still the same.

What happened?

Comment: Does it matter? Use search to reduce the search results to a manageable result set, not to break search.